# How to add an external stylesheet/js file to a UIWebView without having it stored?

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, stylesheet, external

I want to change some CSS properties and HTML content from a random web, so I download and save the html file in the device and load it in a UIWebView to modify it.

The problem occurs when the html has referenced stylesheet/javascript files and they aren't loaded in the UIWebView.

Is there a way to access automatically to these files?
I've thought of getting the path through javascript and add the web url to it, and then download... but first I'll have to check if the path is relative or absolute and that...

Is there an easy and clean way to do this?
(I have the same problem with the images that are not url linked...)
Any idea would be appreciated :)